# How to solve DATA null issue that occured when capturing image through camera

Tags: android

I am writing an Android application where I need to display Image Captured through Camera.
I am using Android 2.1 I tested in emulator. I am trying to capture the image  , but how to display the captured Image on Screen.

My activity is as follows:

```
public class ImageCaptureActivity extends Activity {
                /** Called when the activity is first created. */   
                @Override    
                public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
                    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
                    setContentView(R.layout.main);
                    Uri mImageCaptureUri = Uri.fromFile(new File(
                            "/sdcard/gift2.JPG"));
                    Intent intent = new Intent(
                            "android.media.action.IMAGE_CAPTURE");
                    intent.putExtra(
                            android.provider.MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT,
                            mImageCaptureUri);
                    startActivityForResult(intent, 0);
                }

                protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode,
                        int resultCode, Intent data) {
                    if (requestCode == 0
                            && resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
                        Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "ImageCaptured",
                                Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                        Uri chosenImageUri = data.getData();
                        Bitmap mBitmap = null;
                        try {
                            mBitmap = Media.getBitmap(
                                    this.getContentResolver(),
                                    chosenImageUri);
                        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        } catch (IOException e) {
                            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                        ImageView img = new ImageView(this);
                        img.setImageBitmap(mBitmap);
                        setContentView(img);
                    }
                }
```

When I execute this class . After capturing image  through camera and clicking  "ok" I am getting null pointer exception at  the statement "Uri chosenImageUri = data.getData();" 
Can anyone help me in sorting out this issue.

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Yes my doubt is why data is null

Comment: CAN ANYONE HELP ME IN SOLVING THIS ISSUE PLZ?

Comment: If you already knew that data was null and where wondering why, then you should have asked that question, rather than the about the null pointer exception that results from it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, I confirm data `Intent` is always `null` here with my app. However I don't know why.. Just a statement of fact.

Since you pass an image path to Camera, then in `onActivityResult()` you can read/access the file for the passed path. You just need to keep that path in your `ImageCaptureActivity`. Hopefully you know [how to keep](http://developer.android.com/training/basics/activity-lifecycle/recreating.html) an `Activity` state.

Comment: So, is there any way in which we can pass an Image as intent to camera and retrieve it through the intent and display it?

Answer (score 4):

I had the same problem. Well, maybe it's not the same source but I had the same result.
The source of this problem was that Android was loosing track of the URI because when the "android.media.action.IMAGE_CAPTURE" Activity started (when you start to see what the camera sees), I changed the orientation of the phone to LANDSCAPE... (witch is the default camera shooting orientation - and I'm guessing our AVD is simulating the Landscape too). Yeah, that was the source of quite a headache!
If I kept the phone in PORTRAIT to take my picture, the bug did not show (and I had a valid URI ^^).
So the simple fix was to add the following code in the Manifest:

```
android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation"
```

Pasted it for the Activity that launched the "android.media.action.IMAGE_CAPTURE" Activity (in your case "ImageCaptureActivity").
That fixed it (and I hope it does for you - if it's not too late)!

Comment: There are many other cases (like other types of config changes, e.g. font size or locale change, or OS may simply kill any invisible Activity while Camera app is in the foreground to get more free RAM for image processing). The correct way is to use built-in activity state tracking mechanism: http://developer.android.com/training/basics/activity-lifecycle/recreating.html

Answer (score 0):

when you pass Uri (I mean path to create image from camera), by saying

```
intent.putExtra(android.provider.MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT,mImageCaptureUri);
```

then you must be careful that, this returns null data @ activityresult !
so you wont get anything in data. Rather you will be able to access the image directly by the path you provided while creation of it.

Refer: [Android Camera : data intent returns null](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9890757/android-camera-data-intent-returns-null#answer-10779050)

Answer (score -1):

> I am getting null pointer exception at the statement "Uri chosenImageUri = data.getData();"

This is probably because data is null and you are trying to call one of it's methods.

Verify that an object is non-null before you call it's methods.

Comment: I think he might be asking why data is null, as data is a parameter of the call back function.

Comment: Yes my doubt is why data is null