# Android Camera : data intent returns null

Tags: android, android-camera, android-imageview

I have an Android application which contains multiple activities.

In one of them I'm using a button which will call the device camera:

```
public void onClick(View view) {
    Intent photoIntent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
    startActivityForResult(photoIntent, IMAGE_CAPTURE);
}
```

In the same activity I call the `onActivityResult` method for the image result:

```java
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    if (requestCode == IMAGE_CAPTURE) {
        if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
            Bitmap image = (Bitmap) data.getExtras().get("data");
            ImageView imageview = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.pic);
            imageview.setImageBitmap(image);
        } else if (resultCode == RESULT_CANCELED) {
            Toast.makeText(this, "CANCELED ", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    }
}
```

The problem is that the intent `data` is null and the `onActivityResult` method turns directly to the `(resultCode == RESULT_CANCELED)` and the application returns to the previous activity.

How can I fix this issue so that after calling the camera, the application returns to the current activity which contains an `ImageView` which will contain the picture taken?

Comment: have a look on this answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18120775/android-android-provider-mediastore-action-video-capture-return-null-onactivityr/18207723#18207723

Answer (score 251):

The default Android camera application returns a non-null intent only when passing back a thumbnail in the returned Intent. If you pass `EXTRA_OUTPUT` with a URI to write to, it will return a `null` intent and the picture is in the URI that you passed in.

You can verify this by looking at the camera app's source code on GitHub:

- https://github.com/android/platform_packages_apps_camera/blob/gingerbread-release/src/com/android/camera/Camera.java#L1186

  ```
  Bundle newExtras = new Bundle();
  if (mCropValue.equals("circle")) {
      newExtras.putString("circleCrop", "true");
  }
  if (mSaveUri != null) {
      newExtras.putParcelable(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, mSaveUri);
  } else {
      newExtras.putBoolean("return-data", true);
  }
  ```

I would guess that you're either passing in `EXTRA_OUTPUT` somehow, or the camera app on your phone works differently.

Comment: how would I fix the put Extra functionality, which give non null intent in camera onActivityResult

Comment: Really helpful answer I wish I could accept it for others to find the solution more efficiently.

Comment: The link you posted, is not anymore valid.

Comment: I fixed the link to point to Gingerbread. Not sure where it is in the latest release.

Comment: Question: Is RESULT_CANCELED expected when you specify the EXTRA_OUTPUT parameter?

Comment: @johnnyZ not is it not. I found out you need to supply a uri.fromFile() to get it to work. Uri.parse did not work for me

Comment: hi this is not working for me  i get an error - Unable to decode stream: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'char[] java.lang.String.toCharArray()' on a null object reference

Comment: Could we inhiert the camera class and just change that one method to allow both, or is it harder then that?

Comment: Confusion possibly comes from [android page](https://developer.android.com/training/camera/photobasics)

Comment: How does this make since?  If the data object is null, then how are you supposed to get the extras that are part of the data object since it's null

Comment: I'm confused. Is this supposed to be a solution or just guidance on how it works and why it returns null?

Answer (score 19):

I found an easy answer. it works!!

```
private void openCameraForResult(int requestCode){
    Intent photo = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
    Uri uri  = Uri.parse("file:///sdcard/photo.jpg");
    photo.putExtra(android.provider.MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, uri);
    startActivityForResult(photo,requestCode);
}

if (requestCode == CAMERA_REQUEST_CODE) {
        if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
            File file = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getPath(), "photo.jpg");
            Uri uri = Uri.fromFile(file);
            Bitmap bitmap;
            try {
                bitmap = MediaStore.Images.Media.getBitmap(getContentResolver(), uri);
                bitmap = cropAndScale(bitmap, 300); // if you mind scaling
                profileImageView.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
            } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

        }
    }
```

if you would like to crop and scale this image

```
public static  Bitmap cropAndScale (Bitmap source, int scale){
    int factor = source.getHeight() <= source.getWidth() ? source.getHeight(): source.getWidth();
    int longer = source.getHeight() >= source.getWidth() ? source.getHeight(): source.getWidth();
    int x = source.getHeight() >= source.getWidth() ?0:(longer-factor)/2;
    int y = source.getHeight() <= source.getWidth() ?0:(longer-factor)/2;
    source = Bitmap.createBitmap(source, x, y, factor, factor);
    source = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(source, scale, scale, false);
    return source;
}
```

Comment: It gives a `FileUriExposedException` on modern SDK versions.

Comment: You have to define the androidx.core.content.FileProvider and @xml/filepath

Comment: thanks this worked for me. But I used contentResolver for creating the path.

Answer (score 14):

I've had experienced this problem, the `intent` is not null but the information sent via this `intent` is not received in `onActivityResult()`.

[image]

This is a better solution using [getContentResolver()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context.html#getContentResolver()):

```
    private Uri imageUri;
    private ImageView myImageView;
    private Bitmap thumbnail;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
      
      ...
      ...    
      ...
      myImageview = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.pic); 

      values = new ContentValues();
      values.put(MediaStore.Images.Media.TITLE, "MyPicture");
      values.put(MediaStore.Images.Media.DESCRIPTION, "Photo taken on " + System.currentTimeMillis());
      imageUri = getContentResolver().insert(MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI, values);
      Intent intent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
      intent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, imageUri);
      startActivityForResult(intent, PICTURE_RESULT);
  }
```

The `onActivityResult()` gets a bitmap stored by [getContentResolver()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context.html#getContentResolver()):

```java
     @Override
     protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
         super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

         if (requestCode == REQUEST_CODE_TAKE_PHOTO && resultCode == RESULT_OK) {

             Bitmap bitmap;
             try {
                 bitmap = MediaStore.Images.Media.getBitmap(getContentResolver(), imageUri);
                 myImageView.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
             } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                 e.printStackTrace();
             } catch (IOException e) {
                 e.printStackTrace();
             }
         }
     }
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Check my example in GitHub:

https://github.com/Jorgesys/TakePicture

Comment: This puts the a new file on /.../Pictures every time you use it. Any way to avoid it?

Comment: This requires External Storage Write permission.

Answer (score 7):

### Simple working camera app avoiding the null intent problem

**- all changed code included in this reply; close to android tutorial**

I've been spending plenty of time on this issue, so I decided to create an account and share my outcomes with you.

The official android tutorial ["Taking Photos Simply"](https://developer.android.com/training/camera/photobasics.html) turned out to not quite hold what it promised.
The code provided there did not work on my device: a Samsung Galaxy S4 Mini GT-I9195 running android version 4.4.2 / KitKat / API Level 19.

I figured out that the main problem was the following line in the method invoked when capturing the photo (`dispatchTakePictureIntent` in the tutorial):

```
takePictureIntent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, photoURI);
```

It resulted in the intent subsequently catched by `onActivityResult` being null.

To solve this problem, I pulled much inspiration out of earlier replies here and some helpful posts on github (mostly [this one by deepwinter](https://github.com/deepwinter/AndroidCameraTester/blob/master/src/com/example/cameratester/MainActivity.java) - big thanks to him; you might want to check out his reply on a closely related [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1910608/android-action-image-capture-intent) as well).

Following these pleasant pieces of advice, I chose the strategy of deleting the mentioned `putExtra` line and doing the corresponding thing of getting back the taken picture from the camera within the onActivityResult() method instead.
The decisive lines of code to get back the bitmap associated with the picture are:

```
        Uri uri = intent.getData();
        Bitmap bitmap = null;
        try {
            bitmap = MediaStore.Images.Media.getBitmap(this.getContentResolver(), uri);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

I created an exemplary app which just has the ability to take a picture, save it on the SD card and display it. 
I think this might be helpful to people in the same situation as me when I stumbled on this issue, since the current help suggestions mostly refer to rather extensive github posts which do the thing in question but aren't too easy to oversee for newbies like me.
With respect to the file system Android Studio creates per default when creating a new project, I just had to change three files for my purpose:

activity_main.xml :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical"
tools:context="com.example.android.simpleworkingcameraapp.MainActivity">

<Button
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:onClick="takePicAndDisplayIt"
    android:text="Take a pic and display it." />

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/image1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="200dp" />

</LinearLayout>
```

MainActivity.java :

```
package com.example.android.simpleworkingcameraapp;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.media.Image;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Environment;
import android.provider.MediaStore;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.Date;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

private ImageView image;
static final int REQUEST_TAKE_PHOTO = 1;
String mCurrentPhotoPath;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    image = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.image1);
}

// copied from the android development pages; just added a Toast to show the storage location
private File createImageFile() throws IOException {
    // Create an image file name
    String timeStamp = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd_HHmm").format(new Date());
    String imageFileName = "JPEG_" + timeStamp + "_";
    File storageDir = getExternalFilesDir(Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES);
    File image = File.createTempFile(
            imageFileName,  /* prefix */
            ".jpg",         /* suffix */
            storageDir      /* directory */
    );

    // Save a file: path for use with ACTION_VIEW intents
    mCurrentPhotoPath = image.getAbsolutePath();
    Toast.makeText(this, mCurrentPhotoPath, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    return image;
}

public void takePicAndDisplayIt(View view) {
    Intent intent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
    if (intent.resolveActivity(getPackageManager()) != null) {
        File file = null;
        try {
            file = createImageFile();
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            // Error occurred while creating the File
        }

        startActivityForResult(intent, REQUEST_TAKE_PHOTO);
    }
}

@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultcode, Intent intent) {
    if (requestCode == REQUEST_TAKE_PHOTO && resultcode == RESULT_OK) {
        Uri uri = intent.getData();
        Bitmap bitmap = null;
        try {
            bitmap = MediaStore.Images.Media.getBitmap(this.getContentResolver(), uri);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        image.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
    }
}
}
```

AndroidManifest.xml :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.example.android.simpleworkingcameraapp">


<!--only added paragraph-->
<uses-feature
    android:name="android.hardware.camera"
    android:required="true" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />  <!-- only crucial line to add; for me it still worked without the other lines in this paragraph -->
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />


<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
    <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
</application>

</manifest>
```

Note that the solution I found for the problem also led to a simplification of the android manifest file: the changes suggested by the android tutorial in terms of adding a provider are no longer needed since I am not making use of any in my java code. Hence, only few standard lines -mostly regarding permissions- had to be added to the manifest file.

It might additionally be valuable to point out that Android Studio's autoimport may not be capable of handling `java.text.SimpleDateFormat` and `java.util.Date`. I had to import both of them manually.

Comment: this solutions requires STORAGE permission, which is not very good approach.

Comment: The question clearly states that the Intent parameter named "data" passed in to onActivityResult() is null, while your solution then goes ahead and tries to use that.

Comment: The methd "MediaStore.Images.Media.getBitmap" it is deprecated.

Answer (score 1):

Probably because you had something like this?

```
Intent takePictureIntent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);                        
Uri fileUri =  CommonUtilities.getTBCameraOutputMediaFileUri();                  
takePictureIntent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, fileUri);                        
startActivityForResult(takePictureIntent, 2);
```

However you must not put the extra output into the intent, because then the data goes into the URI instead of the data variable. For that reason, you have to take the two lines in the middle out, so that you have

```
Intent takePictureIntent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
startActivityForResult(takePictureIntent, 2);
```

That´s what caused the problem for me, hope that helped.

Comment: This answer is misleading. You'll get a thumbnail instead of full-sized photo without putting MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT. It's highlighted in the docs and in other answers.

Comment: Absolutely is this answer misleading.

Comment: this is a misleading answer.

Answer (score 0):

To Access the Camera and take pictures and set ImageView on Android

You have to use `Uri file = Uri.fromFile(getOutputMediaFile());` for marshmallow.

Use below link to get path

https://androidkennel.org/android-camera-access-tutorial/

Answer (score 0):

Kotlin code that works for me:

```
 private fun takePhotoFromCamera() {
          val intent = Intent(android.provider.MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE)
        startActivityForResult(intent, PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_TAKE_PICTURE_CAMERA)
      }
```

And get Result :

```
 override fun onActivityResult(requestCode: Int, resultCode: Int, data: Intent?) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data)
 if (requestCode == PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_TAKE_PICTURE_CAMERA) {
         if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
           val photo: Bitmap? =  MediaStore.Images.Media.getBitmap(this.contentResolver, Uri.parse( data!!.dataString)   )
            // Do something here : set image to an ImageView or save it ..   
              imgV_pic.imageBitmap = photo 
        } else if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_CANCELED) {
            Log.i(TAG, "Camera  , RESULT_CANCELED ")
        }

    }

}
```

and don't forget to declare request code:

```
companion object {
 const val PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_TAKE_PICTURE_CAMERA = 300
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

After much try and study, I was able to figure it out. First, the variable data from Intent will always be null so, therefore, checking for `!null` will crash your app so long you are passing a URI to startActivityForResult.Follow the example below.
I will be using Kotlin.

1. Open the camera intent

   ```
   fun addBathroomPhoto(){
   addbathroomphoto.setOnClickListener{

       request_capture_image=2

       var takePictureIntent:Intent?
       takePictureIntent =Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE)
       if(takePictureIntent.resolveActivity(activity?.getPackageManager()) != null){

           val photoFile: File? = try {
               createImageFile()
           } catch (ex: IOException) {
               // Error occurred while creating the File

               null
           }

           if (photoFile != null) {
               val photoURI: Uri = FileProvider.getUriForFile(
                   activity!!,
                   "ogavenue.ng.hotelroomkeeping.fileprovider",photoFile)
               takePictureIntent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT,
                   photoURI);
               startActivityForResult(takePictureIntent,
                   request_capture_image);
           }


       }

   }
   ```

   }`
2. Create the createImageFile().But you MUST make the imageFilePath variable global. Example on how to create it is on Android official documentation and pretty straightforward
3. Get Intent

   ```
    override fun onActivityResult(requestCode: Int, resultCode: Int, data: Intent?) {

   if (requestCode == 1 && resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
       add_room_photo_txt.text=""
       var myBitmap=BitmapFactory.decodeFile(imageFilePath)
       addroomphoto.setImageBitmap(myBitmap)
       var file=File(imageFilePath)
       var fis=FileInputStream(file)
       var bm = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(fis);
       roomphoto=getBytesFromBitmap(bm) }}
   ```
4. The getBytesFromBitmap method

   ```
     fun getBytesFromBitmap(bitmap:Bitmap):ByteArray{

     var stream=ByteArrayOutputStream()
     bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, stream);
     return stream.toByteArray();
     }
   ```

I hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

I used contentResolver to create the path and it worked.

```
var values = ContentValues()
            values.put(MediaStore.Images.Media.TITLE, "MyPicture")
            values.put(
                MediaStore.Images.Media.DESCRIPTION,
                "Photo taken on " + System.currentTimeMillis()
            )
            cameraUri = contentResolver.insert(MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI, values)

            val cameraIntent = Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE)
            cameraIntent.putExtra(android.provider.MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, cameraUri);
            startActivityForResult(cameraIntent, REQUEST_CODE)
```

Answer (score 0):

it still occurs even now 2022, i fix it as follow:

```
 if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.N) { // android7.0
                    photoUri= FileProvider.getUriForFile(
                            MainActivity.this,
                            BuildConfig.APPLICATION_ID + ".provider",
                            new File(mCameraFilePath));
                    intent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, photoUri);
                } else {
                    photoUri = Uri.fromFile(new File(mCameraFilePath));
                    intent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT,photoUri);
                }
```

,oh...just add a viriable(photoUri) to your activity! then

```
filePathCallback.onReceiveValue(new Uri[]{ photoUri });
```

Answer (score -1):

The following code works for me:

```
Intent cameraIntent = new Intent(android.provider.MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
startActivityForResult(cameraIntent, 2);
```

And here is the result:

```
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent imageReturnedIntent)
{ 
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, imageReturnedIntent);

    if(resultCode == RESULT_OK)
    {
        Uri selectedImage = imageReturnedIntent.getData();
        ImageView photo = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.add_contact_label_photo);
        Bitmap mBitmap = null;
        try
        {
            mBitmap = Media.getBitmap(this.getContentResolver(), selectedImage);
        }
        catch (IOException e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I tested it but it the same issue :(

Comment: i am getting `imageReturnedIntent.getData()` value null. I am creating intent same as yours. Doesn't putted any extra params.