# MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT renders data null, other way to save photos?

Tags: java, android, android-intent, camera

Google offers this versatile code for taking photos via an intent:

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    // create Intent to take a picture and return control to the calling application
    Intent intent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);

    fileUri = getOutputMediaFileUri(MEDIA_TYPE_IMAGE); // create a file to save the image
    intent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, fileUri); // set the image file name

    // start the image capture Intent
    startActivityForResult(intent, CAPTURE_IMAGE_ACTIVITY_REQUEST_CODE);
}
```

The problem is that if you're like me and you want to pass the photos as extras, using `EXTRA_OUTPUT` seemingly runs off with the photo data and makes subsequent actions think the intent data is null.

[It appears](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1910608/android-action-image-capture-intent) this is a big bug with Android.

I'm trying to take a photo then display it as a thumbnail in a new view. I'd like to have it saved as a full sized image in the user's gallery. Does anyone know a way to specify the image location without using `EXTRA_OUTPUT`?

Here's what I have currently:

```
public void takePhoto(View view) {
    Intent takePictureIntent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);

    fileUri = getOutputMediaFileUri(MEDIA_TYPE_IMAGE);
//  takePictureIntent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, fileUri);

    startActivityForResult(takePictureIntent, CAMERA_REQUEST_CODE);
}

/** Create a file Uri for saving an image or video */
private static Uri getOutputMediaFileUri(int type){
      return Uri.fromFile(getOutputMediaFile(type));
}

/** Create a File for saving an image or video */
@SuppressLint("SimpleDateFormat")
private static File getOutputMediaFile(int type){

    File mediaStorageDir = new File(Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(
              Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES), "JoshuaTree");

    if (! mediaStorageDir.exists()){
        if (! mediaStorageDir.mkdirs()){
            Log.d("JoshuaTree", "failed to create directory");
            return null;
        }
    }

    // Create a media file name
    String timeStamp = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd_HHmmss").format(new Date());
    File mediaFile;
    if (type == MEDIA_TYPE_IMAGE){
        mediaFile = new File(mediaStorageDir.getPath() + File.separator +
        "IMG_"+ timeStamp + ".jpg");
    } else {
        return null;
    }

    return mediaFile;
}

@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    if (requestCode == CAMERA_REQUEST_CODE) {
        if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
            handleSmallCameraPhoto(data);
        }
    }
}


private void handleSmallCameraPhoto(Intent intent) {
    Bundle extras = intent.getExtras();
    mImageBitmap = (Bitmap) extras.get("data");
    Intent displayIntent = new Intent(this, DisplayPhotoActivity.class);
    displayIntent.putExtra("BitmapImage", mImageBitmap);
    startActivity(displayIntent);
}
```

}

Comment: try this takePictureIntent.putExtra("return-data", true);

Comment: @JRowan No sign of it saving :|

Comment: make mediaFile global to your class or even static if you want then youll always have that file ready

Comment: Have you set the permission to write to the external storage?

Answer (score 19):

If you specified MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, the image taken will be written to that path, and no data will given to onActivityResult. You can read the image from what you specified.

See another solved same question here: [Android Camera : data intent returns null](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9890757/android-camera-data-intent-returns-null)

Comment: That's nice, but EXTRA_OUTPUT just prevents the camera from taking pictures at all in my application. I hope they just throw out the entire camera library and write a new one soon.

Comment: Just adding that the path MUST end in a directory. If you try to specify a file like picture.jpg, it will crash internally and refuse to acknowledge your ACCEPT_PICTURE button clicks in the camera.

Comment: Also, Camera2 is available in API 21 so soon we won't have to deal with all of this obscure stuff any more!

Comment: yes your are right. But the docs tells us getData should return the URI of the image. http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/media/camera.html#intent-receive

Comment: Actually in some device (motorola razr for instance) you get the data back.

Answer (score 1):

Basically, there are two ways to retrieve the image from Camera, if you use to send a captured image through intent extras you cannot retrieve it on ActivityResult on intent.getData() ' because it saves the image data through extras.

So the idea is:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
startActivityForResult(intent, CAPTURE_IMAGE_ACTIVITY_REQUEST_CODE);
```

And retrieving it on ActivityResults checking the retrieved intent:

```
    @Override  
    public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent intent) {        
    if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {            
        if (requestCode == CAPTURE_IMAGE_ACTIVITY_REQUEST_CODE) {                
            if (intent.getData() != null) {                    
                ParcelFileDescriptor parcelFileDescriptor = context.getContentResolver().openFileDescriptor(intent.getData(), "r");                           
                FileDescriptor fileDescriptor = parcelFileDescriptor.getFileDescriptor();                      
                Bitmap image = BitmapFactory.decodeFileDescriptor(fileDescriptor);                     
                parcelFileDescriptor.close();
            } else {                    
                Bitmap imageRetrieved = (Bitmap) intent.getExtras().get("data");              
            }           
        } 
    }
}
```

Comment: But when i save photo using File Output Stream, the image bitmap rotates 270 degress.

Comment: There is a typo in:
ParcelFileDescriptor parcelFileDescriptor = context.getContentResolver().openFileDescriptor(intent.getData()), "r")

There is an extra parenthesis after "getData()"

Comment: Thx @RodrigoBorba

Comment: Thank you so much. I tried intent.data instead of intent.extras.get("data")

Answer (score 0):

Here is how you can achieve what you want:

```
public void onClick(View v) 
  {

    switch(v.getId())

          {

           case R.id.iBCamera:


            File image = new File(appFolderCheckandCreate(), "img" + getTimeStamp() + ".jpg");
            Uri uriSavedImage = Uri.fromFile(image);

            Intent i = new Intent(android.provider.MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
            i.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, uriSavedImage);
            i.putExtra("return-data", true);
            startActivityForResult(i, CAMERA_RESULT);

            break;

           }
}

@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) 
{

    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

    switch(requestCode)

          {

          case CAMERA_RESULT:

                       if(resultCode==RESULT_OK)
                          {
                           handleSmallCameraPhoto(uriSavedImage);     
                          }
                     break;

          }

 }

     private void handleSmallCameraPhoto(Uri uri) 
        {
           Bitmap bmp=null;

              try {
                bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(getContentResolver().openInputStream(uri));
                   } 
                   catch (FileNotFoundException e) 
                   {

                 e.printStackTrace();
                }


               Intent displayIntent = new Intent(this, DisplayPhotoActivity.class);
             displayIntent.putExtra("BitmapImage", bmp);
            startActivity(displayIntent);


       }

private String appFolderCheckandCreate(){

    String appFolderPath="";
    File externalStorage = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();

    if (externalStorage.canWrite()) 
    {
        appFolderPath = externalStorage.getAbsolutePath() + "/MyApp";
        File dir = new File(appFolderPath);

        if (!dir.exists()) 
        {
              dir.mkdirs();
        }

    }
    else
    {
      showToast("  Storage media not found or is full ! ");
    }

    return appFolderPath;
}



 private String getTimeStamp() {

    final long timestamp = new Date().getTime();

    final Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
                   cal.setTimeInMillis(timestamp);

    final String timeString = new SimpleDateFormat("HH_mm_ss_SSS").format(cal.getTime());


    return timeString;
}
```

**Edit:**

Add these to Manifest:

**Starting Api 19 and above READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE should be declared explicitly**

```
     *<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />*
     <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

to you manifest.

Comment: Yes, Agree on 1st point w.r.t time when its been answered. But now you have to have READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE starting API 19. Have a look http://developer.android.com/reference/android/Manifest.permission.html#READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE (no offence but don't agree on 2 & 3 though)

Comment: Only if you actually require SD card access, since you have access to your sandboxed file structure. As for the styling, there are just so many unnecessary white spaces, new lines, not aligned brackets and indents. You should read Clean Code, that books explains it better than I can.

Answer (score 0):

Try this one `android.provider.MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT` hope will solve your bug. The following code works for me:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
fileUri = getOutputMediaFileUri(MEDIA_TYPE_IMAGE); 
intent.putExtra(android.provider.MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, fileUri); 
startActivityForResult(intent, CAPTURE_IMAGE_ACTIVITY_REQUEST_CODE);
```

I was facing same problem, every time getting null while retrieving data on other activity with `getIntent().getData()` then solved by writting complete `android.provider.MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT` this solved my bug.