# Call to system Camera returns null in fragment,but in activity it's ok

Tags: android, android-camera

```
Intent openCameraIntent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
openCameraIntent.putExtra("return-data", true);
Uri imageUri = Uri.fromFile(new File(path));
openCameraIntent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, imageUri);
activity.startActivityForResult(openCameraIntent, CROP);
```

The code is in a ImageView click handler. When the view is in an activity, it's ok.
But when the view is in a fragment, the onActivityResult data is `null`

Comment: instead of calling activity.startActivityForResult(openCameraIntent, CROP); you should call startActivityForResult(openCameraIntent, CROP); from fragment

Comment: onActivityResult is callback,and but data is null

Answer (score 1):

Whenever you specified MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, the image taken will be written to that path, and no data will given to onActivityResult. You can read the image from what you specified.

Otherwise to get data from result callback write your intent without specifying the Output uri as

```
Intent cameraIntent = new Intent(android.provider.MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
startActivityForResult(cameraIntent, CROP);
```

You can take a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10779050) answer also

Comment: You need to remove the data null check condition. It works fine after that

Answer (score 0):

```
            Intent intent = new Intent(
                                        MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);

                                private Uri mImageCaptureUri = Uri.fromFile(new File(
                                        Environment
                                                .getExternalStorageDirectory(),
                                        "tmp_avatar_"
                                                + String.valueOf(System
                                                        .currentTimeMillis())
                                                + ".jpg"));

                                intent.putExtra(
                                        android.provider.MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT,
                                        mImageCaptureUri);

                                try {


                                       intent.putExtra("return-data", true);

                                    startActivityForResult(intent,
                                            PICK_FROM_CAMERA);
                                } catch (ActivityNotFoundException e) {
                                    e.printStackTrace();
                                }
```

then on activityresult put

```
if(requestCode==PICK_FROM_CAMERA)
{

        doCrop();

}

 else if(requestCode==CROP_FROM_CAMERA)
  {

        Bundle extras = data.getExtras();

        Log.e("extras received from crop", extras.toString() + "yes yes");

        if (extras != null) {
            Bitmap photo = extras.getParcelable("data");



        }

        File f = new File(mImageCaptureUri.getPath());

        if (f.exists())
            f.delete();


    }
```

here's do crop method

```
            private void doCrop() {

    final ArrayList<CropOption> cropOptions = new ArrayList<CropOption>();

    Intent intent = new Intent("com.android.camera.action.CROP");
    intent.setType("image/*");

    List<ResolveInfo> list = getActivity().getPackageManager()
            .queryIntentActivities(intent, 0);

    int size = list.size();

    if (size == 0) {
        Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Can not find image crop app",
                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        return;
    } else {
        intent.setData(mImageCaptureUri);

        intent.putExtra("outputX", 200);
        intent.putExtra("outputY", 200);
        intent.putExtra("aspectX", 1);
        intent.putExtra("aspectY", 1);
        intent.putExtra("scale", true);
        intent.putExtra("return-data", true);

        if (size == 1) {

            Intent i = new Intent(intent);
            ResolveInfo res = list.get(0);

            i.setComponent(new ComponentName(res.activityInfo.packageName,
                    res.activityInfo.name));

        startActivityForResult(i, CROP_FROM_CAMERA);
        } else {
            for (ResolveInfo res : list) {
                final CropOption co = new CropOption();

                co.title = getActivity().getPackageManager()
                        .getApplicationLabel(
                                res.activityInfo.applicationInfo);
                co.icon = getActivity().getPackageManager()
                        .getApplicationIcon(
                                res.activityInfo.applicationInfo);
                co.appIntent = new Intent(intent);

                co.appIntent
                        .setComponent(new ComponentName(
                                res.activityInfo.packageName,
                                res.activityInfo.name));

                cropOptions.add(co);
            }

            CropOptionAdapter adapter = new CropOptionAdapter(
                    getActivity(), cropOptions);

            AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(
                    getActivity());
            builder.setTitle("Choose Crop App");
            builder.setAdapter(adapter,
                    new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int item) {
                            startActivityForResult(
                                    cropOptions.get(item).appIntent,
                                    CROP_FROM_CAMERA);
                        }
                    });

            builder.setOnCancelListener(new DialogInterface.OnCancelListener() {
                @Override
                public void onCancel(DialogInterface dialog) {

                    if (mImageCaptureUri != null) {
                        getActivity().getContentResolver().delete(
                                mImageCaptureUri, null, null);
                        mImageCaptureUri = null;
                    }
                }
            });

            AlertDialog alert = builder.create();

            alert.show();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: still you get data null when you used this code..??

Comment: if (data==null) {return;}if (currentTabIndex==2) {storeFragment.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);}

Comment: i delete if(data==null) the problem solve，I don't know why，Thank you very much