# I am making an application to take pic, save and display but intent is return null in above version and in android 1.6 its working fine

Tags: android, android-camera-intent

I am using this code it is working fine in 1.6 but it is crashing in 4.4?

```
 Intent intent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
                fileUri = new ExternalStorage(getApplicationContext()).getAlbumStorageDir(); // create a file to save the image
                intent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, fileUri); // set the image file name
                // start the image capture Intent
                startActivityForResult(intent, CAPTURE_IMAGE_ACTIVITY_REQUEST_CODE);


    /*in onActivityResult*/
if (requestCode == CAPTURE_IMAGE_ACTIVITY_REQUEST_CODE) {
            if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
                Uri uri = data.getData();
                try {
                    Bitmap bitmap = MediaStore.Images.Media.getBitmap(getContentResolver(), uri);
                    ImageView imageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.image);
                    imageView.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            } else if (resultCode == RESULT_CANCELED) {
            } else {
            }
        }
```

I have gone through several post but all I didn't find correct one.

Comment: Hi dude.., 

this link may help you same problem is faced here also. Check it out.

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9890757/android-camera-data-intent-returns-null

Answer (score 0):

There is no requirement for `ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE` to return a `Uri` via `onActivityResult()`.

You know where the image should be stored, as you are providing that via `EXTRA_OUTPUT`. Use the value you put into `EXTRA_OUTPUT`, rather than `data.getData()`.