# Android - Check button after taking picture using camera doesn't do anything

Tags: android, camera

So.. I'm trying to choose a picture using both camera and gallery, then pass it to an external library to crop image.

The problem lies with saving image after taking it with the camera. I've managed to get the camera running and take an image with it, then it display the image and the default Android Ok and back button. The Ok button responds to touch (as touch effect can be seen) but it doesn't do anything.

Here's the code for getting the file ready to save

```
date = calendar.getTime();
        SimpleDateFormat simpleDateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("ddMMyyyyHHmmss");
        dateString = simpleDateFormat.format(date);
        dateBuilder = new StringBuilder().append(dateString).append(".jpg");
        SAMPLE_CROPPED_IMAGE_NAME = dateBuilder.toString();

        final String cameraDir = Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES) + "/SamplePics/";
        newDir = new File(cameraDir);
        newDir.mkdirs();
```

This is the code for camera function

```
RelativeLayout.OnClickListener photoCameraWrapperHandler = new RelativeLayout.OnClickListener(){

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            //Intent intent = new Intent(SignupStepThreeActivity.this, SignupStepFourActivity.class);
            //startActivity(intent);
            String cameraFile = SAMPLE_CROPPED_IMAGE_NAME;
            newFile = new File(cameraFile);
            try {
                newFile.createNewFile();
            }
            catch (IOException e)
            {
            }

            Uri outputFileUri = Uri.fromFile(newFile);
            Intent cameraIntent = new Intent(android.provider.MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
            cameraIntent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, outputFileUri);
            startActivityForResult(cameraIntent, CAMERA_REQUEST);
        }
    };
```

And here's the `onActivityResult` :

```
private static final int CAMERA_REQUEST = 1888;
private static final int REQUEST_SELECT_PICTURE = 0x01;

@Override
    public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
            if (requestCode == REQUEST_SELECT_PICTURE || requestCode == CAMERA_REQUEST) {
                final Uri selectedUri = data.getData();
                if (selectedUri != null) {
                    startCropActivity(data.getData());
                } else {
                    Toast.makeText(SignupStepThreeActivity.this, R.string.toast_cannot_retrieve_selected_image, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            } else if (requestCode == UCrop.REQUEST_CROP) {
                handleCropResult(data);
            }
        }
        if (resultCode == UCrop.RESULT_ERROR) {
            handleCropError(data);
        }
    }
```

Several updates before, it crashes when I click on camera button, I suspected it was because of I kind of take the uri of the image from storage but I haven't created the folder. Now I finally managed to get the camera running but not saving. The create folder part works tho..

Comment: do you set WRITE permission in your AndroidManifest.xml?

Comment: Yes both read for gallery and write for camera `
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>` Wait I think I just realized something, does `WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE` only lets access to `EXTERNAL`?

Comment: "doesn't do anything": is your onActivityResult() called? What is **resultCode**? Please check [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/10779050/192373) if your problem is that **resultCode** is OK, but **data** is null.

Comment: Yes I've found it while going thru Stack's answers, and in fact that's what I needed, `data.getData()` is null, it returns `Bitmap` instead which I have to convert to `Uri`. Check my answer for the solution :D

Answer (score 0):

```
public String getCamerPath(Context context) {
        SharedPreferences prefs = context.getSharedPreferences("setCamerPath", 0);
        String value = prefs.getString("getCamerPath", "");

        return value;

    }

    public void setCamerPath(Context context, String value)

    {
        SharedPreferences prefs = context.getSharedPreferences("setCamerPath", 0);
        SharedPreferences.Editor editor = prefs.edit();
        editor.putString("getCamerPath", value);
        editor.commit();
    }

Uri outputFileUri = Uri.fromFile(newFile);

setCamerPath(this, outputFileUri.getPath());
            Intent cameraIntent = new Intent(android.provider.MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
            cameraIntent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, outputFileUri);
            startActivityForResult(cameraIntent, CAMERA_REQUEST);


@Override
    public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
            if (requestCode == REQUEST_SELECT_PICTURE || requestCode == CAMERA_REQUEST) {

                    startCropActivity(getCamerPath(this));

            } else if (requestCode == UCrop.REQUEST_CROP) {
                handleCropResult(data);
            }
        }
        if (resultCode == UCrop.RESULT_ERROR) {
            handleCropError(data);
        }
    }
```

Comment: `startCropActivity` needs `Uri`.. But `getCamerPath` returns `String`.. Does shared Prefs store the Uri??

Comment: I did this `final Uri selectedUri = Uri.parse(getCamerPath(SignupStepThreeActivity.this));` but it still doesn't do anything when I click on the Ok button..

Comment: you need to debug your code if you get the path in onActivityResult or not

Comment: Nevermind, I'm going to post the result in a bit, it's because of I had `cameraIntent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, outputFileUri);` before starting the camera, I now know that the Data doesn't even have Uri return, but bitmap.. I had to convert Bitmap to Uri and voilaa

Answer (score 0):

In the camera `OnClickListener`, I commented some stuffs like this :

```
Intent cameraIntent = new Intent(android.provider.MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
            //Uri outputFileUri = Uri.fromFile(newFile);
            //cameraIntent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, outputFileUri);
            //setCamerPath(SignupStepThreeActivity.this, outputFileUri.getPath());
            startActivityForResult(cameraIntent, CAMERA_REQUEST);
```

In my `onActivityResult`, I've modified a part of `CAMERA_REQUEST` :

```
else if (requestCode == CAMERA_REQUEST) {
                Uri capturedImageUri = data.getData();
                Bitmap bitmap;
                if (capturedImageUri != null) {
                    startCropActivity(capturedImageUri);
                } else {
                    Toast.makeText(SignupStepThreeActivity.this, R.string.toast_cannot_retrieve_selected_image, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    Bundle extras = data.getExtras();
                    bitmap = (Bitmap) extras.get("data");
                    Uri imageUri = getImageUri(SignupStepThreeActivity.this, bitmap);
                    startCropActivity(imageUri);
                }
            }
```

So basically as I've been reading around for the past 4 hours, `data` is `Intent`. It will always be not null BUT will not always contain `Uri` itself for the image. Because I need the `Uri` for a library I'm using, I use a method called `getImageUri` from another Stackoverflow answer.

```
public static Uri getImageUri(Context inContext, Bitmap inImage)
    {
        ByteArrayOutputStream bytes = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        inImage.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, bytes);
        String path = MediaStore.Images.Media.insertImage(inContext.getContentResolver(), inImage, "Title", null);
        return Uri.parse(path);
    }
```

Now the problem lies with bitmap image quality after taking the image, I'm going to tinker around with it and be back with an update.

Answer (score 0):

```
This can also resolve the problem
@Override
    protected void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
        super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
        Log.d("camera", "onSaveInstance");

        // save file url in bundle as it will be null on screen orientation
        // changes
        outState.putParcelable("file_uri", fileUri);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onRestoreInstanceState(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onRestoreInstanceState(savedInstanceState);
        Log.d("camera", "onRestoreInstance");
        // get the file url
        fileUri = savedInstanceState.getParcelable("file_uri");
    }
```

Comment: Ahh that is for the part where user might press home or anything which sets the app not currently running, right? I used it in another class, thanks though :D