# Camera App. Error on creating File to save it on Storage

Tags: android, image, file, save, android-camera

I don't know why but I'am getting this error when I try to take a Picture:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException: file
at android.net.Uri.fromFile(Uri.java:452)
at zockerbros.com.chatapp.main.Chat_Room.onClick(Chat_Room.java:547)
```

Code for creating File:

```
File createFile() throws IOException{                                   
String timeStamp = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyMMMddd_HHmmss").format(newDate());
String imageFileName = "IMG_"+timeStamp+"_";
File StorgaeDirectory = Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES);

File image = File.createTempFile(imageFileName, ".jpg", StorgaeDirectory);
mImageFileLocation = image.getAbsolutePath();
galleryAddPic(mImageFileLocation);
return image;}
```

Code for taking the Picture:

```
Intent callCameraAppIntent = new Intent();
            callCameraAppIntent.setAction(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);

            File photoFile = null;
            try{
                photoFile = createFile();

            }catch(IOException e){
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            -> Here is the error callCameraAppIntent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, Uri.fromFile(photoFile));

            startActivityForResult(callCameraAppIntent, TAKE_PICTURE);
```

Thanks for your help :)

Comment: does `createFile()` actually create a file or throw `IOException`?

Comment: it creates a file and throws an IOEception when an error happens

Comment: is an error happening?

Comment: It says that the file is null...

Comment: Do you know how to save an image from the camera intent in the storage?

Comment: what android version are you running? does your app have write external storage permission?

Comment: You are probably bitten by this problem with app livecycle: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9890757/android-camera-data-intent-returns-null