# Taking a picture with a camera intent and saving it to a file

Tags: android, camera

I'm trying to get my app to start a camera intent in order to take a picture and save it into a directory as well as show a thumbnail in the main view, but I don't quite seem to get it right. Here's the methods I'm using:

```
@RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.M)
private void dispatchTakePictureIntent() {
    if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(getContext(), android.Manifest.permission.CAMERA) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
            requestPermissions(new String[]{android.Manifest.permission.CAMERA},
                    5);
        }
    }

    Intent takePictureIntent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
    if (takePictureIntent.resolveActivity(getContext().getPackageManager()) != null) {
        File photoFile = null;

        try {
            photoFile.createNewFile();
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
        if(photoFile != null) {
            Uri photoURI = FileProvider.getUriForFile(getContext(),
                    "com.example.android.fileprovider",
                    photoFile);
            takePictureIntent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, photoURI);
            startActivityForResult(takePictureIntent, REQUEST_TAKE_PHOTO);
        }
    }
}
```

And here's the `OnActivityResult`:

```
@Override
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    if (requestCode == REQUEST_TAKE_PHOTO && resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
        Bundle extras = data.getExtras();
        Bitmap imageBitmap = (Bitmap) extras.get("data");
        image.setImageBitmap(imageBitmap);
    }

}
```

I seem to be getting a `NullPointerException` in two different places, at:

- `photoFile.createNewFile();`
- `image.setImageBitmap(imageBitmap);`

How can I fix this?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Android Camera : data intent returns null](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9890757/android-camera-data-intent-returns-null)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change your `onActivityResult` to

```
  @Override
        public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
            super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
            if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {  
                    onCaptureImageResult(data);
            }
        }
```

for setting in a thumbnail pass the `data` in your `ImageView` variable like this:

```
private void onCaptureImageResult(Intent data) {

        Bitmap thumbnail = (Bitmap) data.getExtras().get("data");
        ByteArrayOutputStream bytes = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        thumbnail.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 90, bytes);
        byteArray = bytes.toByteArray();
        encodedImage = Base64.encodeToString(byteArray, Base64.DEFAULT);
        File destination = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(),
                System.currentTimeMillis() + ".jpg");
        FileOutputStream fo;
        try {
            destination.createNewFile();
            fo = new FileOutputStream(destination);
            fo.write(bytes.toByteArray());
            fo.close();
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        imageView.setImageBitmap(thumbnail);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

> NullPointerException in two different places, at photoFile.createNewFile();

use this

```
 File photoFile = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + File.separator + "filename");
```

instead of this

```
File photoFile = null;
```

> NullPointerException in two different places, at image.setImageBitmap(imageBitmap);

just Intilize your `ImageView`

Comment: Please note that `Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()` may not match the `FileProvider` configuration.

Answer (score 0):

`File photoFile = null` — since you are assigning `null` to `photoFile`, you will get a `NullPointerException` whenever you try calling methods on `photoFile`. You need to set `photoFile` to some `File` that is covered by your `FileProvider` configuration, since you are using `FileProvider`. Also note that you can get rid of the `createNewFile()` call, as that is not necessary.

And, since you are using `EXTRA_OUTPUT`, `extras.get("data")` will return `null`. Your image is supposed to be in the location indicated by `photoFile`.

[Here is a sample app](https://github.com/commonsguy/cw-omnibus/tree/v8.8/Camera/FileProvider) demonstrating the use of `ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE` with `FileProvider`.