# Taking picture in fragment callback error

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-intent, camera

I have searched a lot to solve this issue, but couldnt get it fixed.

I am using a camera function in my app and having troubles passing the intent to the callback method. The user can either upload an image from the gallery

```
retrieveFromGallery()
```

which works fine. He also can take a picture

```
takePicture()
```

which causes a crash in

```
onActivityResult()
```

as the intent is null. It is not null however, when I call

```
startActivityForResult(takePictureIntent, REQUEST_TAKE_PHOTO);
```

The picture gets saved in the file path defined, but I want to display it in the app, as I do when I retrieve it from the gallery.
I followed the Android Developer Tutorial, so my code should be the same as there. Only difference: Im using fragments
Any help is greatly appreciated :)

```
private static final int PICK_IMAGE_REQUEST = 2;
private static final int REQUEST_TAKE_PHOTO = 3;

public void retrieveFromGallery() {
    Intent intent = new Intent();
    // Show only images, no videos or anything else
    intent.setType("image/*");
    intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
    // Always show the chooser (if there are multiple options available)
    startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(intent, "Select Picture"), PICK_IMAGE_REQUEST);
}

public void takePicture() {
    Intent takePictureIntent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
    // Ensure that there's a camera activity to handle the intent
    if (takePictureIntent.resolveActivity(this.getActivity().getPackageManager()) != null) {
        // Create the File where the photo should go
        File photoFile = null;
        try {
            photoFile = createImageFile();
            Log.d(LOG_TAG, "creating photofile: " + photoFile);
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            // Error occurred while creating the File
            Log.d(LOG_TAG, "error creating the file" + ex);

        }
        // Continue only if the File was successfully created
        if (photoFile != null) {
            Log.d(LOG_TAG, "temporary photofile path: " + photoFile);
           takePictureIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION);
            Uri photoURI = FileProvider.getUriForFile(this.getActivity(),
                    getActivity().getApplicationContext().getPackageName() + ".fileprovider", photoFile);
            Log.d(LOG_TAG, "uri: " + photoURI);

            takePictureIntent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, photoURI);

            startActivityForResult(takePictureIntent, REQUEST_TAKE_PHOTO);
            Log.d(LOG_TAG, "intent: " + takePictureIntent + " , " + REQUEST_TAKE_PHOTO);
        }

    }
}


@Override
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    if (requestCode == PICK_IMAGE_REQUEST && resultCode == RESULT_OK && data != null && data.getData() != null) {
        Uri uri = data.getData();
        try {
            Bitmap bitmap = MediaStore.Images.Media.getBitmap(this.getActivity().getContentResolver(), uri);
            popupWindowSelectUploadSource.dismiss();
            selectedImage.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            selectedImage.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
            Log.d(LOG_TAG, "img path" + bitmap);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    } else if (requestCode == REQUEST_TAKE_PHOTO && resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
                Log.d(LOG_TAG, "on activity result - intent: " + requestCode + "resultcode "+ resultCode + "data " + data);
                Bundle extras = data.getExtras();
                Bitmap imageBitmap = (Bitmap) extras.get("data");
                popupWindowSelectUploadSource.dismiss();
                selectedImage.setImageBitmap(imageBitmap);
            }

}
```

From my Logcat:

```
  03-18 13:26:36.752 593-593/com.example.myapp D/SpotMap: opening a popup window
  03-18 13:26:37.721 593-593/com.example.myapp D/SpotMap: opening the popup window to select upload source
  03-18 13:26:38.626 593-593/com.example.myapp D/SpotMap: creating photofile:/storage/emulated/0/Android/data/com.example.myapp/files/Pictures/JPEG_20180318_132638_5713532469653547292.jpg
  03-18 13:26:38.627 593-593/com.example.myapp D/SpotMap: temporary photofile: path: /storage/emulated/0/Android/data/com.example.myapp/files/Pictures/JPEG_20180318_132638_5713532469653547292.jpg
  03-18 13:26:38.627 593-593/com.example.myapp D/SpotMap: uri: content://com.example.myapp.fileprovider/my_images/JPEG_20180318_132638_5713532469653547292.jpg
  03-18 13:26:38.681 593-593/com.example.myapp D/SpotMap: intent: Intent { act=android.media.action.IMAGE_CAPTURE flg=0x3 clip={text/uri-list U:content://com.example.myapp.fileprovider/my_images/JPEG_20180318_132638_5713532469653547292.jpg} (has extras) } , 3
  03-18 13:26:38.714 593-593/com.example.myapp D/SpotMap: on Pause
  03-18 13:26:47.444 593-593/com.example.myapp D/SpotMap: on activity result - intent: 3resultcode -1data null
```

My error message:

```
 E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
              Process: com.example.myapp, PID: 593
              java.lang.RuntimeException: Failure delivering result ResultInfo{who=null, request=65539, result=-1, data=null} to activity {com.example.vreeni.StreetMovementApp/com.example.myapp.MainActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.os.Bundle android.content.Intent.getExtras()' on a null object reference
                  at android.app.ActivityThread.deliverResults(ActivityThread.java:4339)
                  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleSendResult(ActivityThread.java:4382)
                  at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap19(Unknown Source:0)
                  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1654)
```

**UPDATE**:

I tried what was suggested in a similar post, I am able to enter into the OnActivityResult method, and just create the URI there. But then, however, it cannot be converted into Bitmap. Returns null.

```
@Override
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    if (requestCode == PICK_IMAGE_REQUEST && resultCode == RESULT_OK && data != null && data.getData() != null) {
        Uri uri = data.getData();
        try {
            Bitmap bitmap = MediaStore.Images.Media.getBitmap(this.getActivity().getContentResolver(), uri);
            popupWindowSelectUploadSource.dismiss();
            selectedImage.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            selectedImage.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
            Log.d(LOG_TAG, "img path" + bitmap);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    } else if (requestCode == REQUEST_TAKE_PHOTO && resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
        File photoFile = null;
        try {
            photoFile = createImageFile();
            Log.d(LOG_TAG, "creating photofile: " + photoFile);
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            // Error occurred while creating the File
            Log.d(LOG_TAG, "error creating the file" + ex);

        }
        if (photoFile != null) {
            Log.d(LOG_TAG, "temporary photofile path: " + photoFile);
            Uri photoURI = FileProvider.getUriForFile(this.getActivity(),
                    getActivity().getApplicationContext().getPackageName() + ".fileprovider", photoFile);
            Log.d(LOG_TAG, "uri: " + photoURI);
            try {
                Bitmap bitmap = MediaStore.Images.Media.getBitmap(this.getActivity().getContentResolver(), photoURI);
                Log.d(LOG_TAG, "bitmap: " + bitmap);
                selectedImage.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                selectedImage.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: can you not just use photoURI since you know that picture is captured

Comment: Thanks for the tip. Tried it with URI, `Bitmap myBitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(photoFile.getAbsolutePath());` and `selectedImage.setImageBitmap(myBitmap);` as well as loading the image using glide now, but no image is being displayed..

Comment: Same result sadly. I just tried to set the image resource with `setImageResource` and that works but any other way to set the image fails. I do still get the uri so I am completely lost in what the problem is

Comment: This is what I get in logcat, when printing `Uri`: `content://com.example.myapp.fileprovider/my_images/JPEG_20180318_173008_5768841254225995534.jpg` Is this not, how it should work?

Comment: `03-18 17:43:00.410 30813-30813/com.example.myapp D/SpotMap: uri: content://com.example.myapp.fileprovider/my_images/JPEG_20180318_174300_2454911568678617064.jpg
03-18 17:43:00.427 30813-30813/com.example.myapp D/SpotMap: intent: Intent { act=android.media.action.IMAGE_CAPTURE } , 3
03-18 17:43:00.479 30813-30813/com.example.myapp D/SpotMap: on Pause
03-18 17:43:07.476 30813-30813/com.example.myapp D/SpotMap: on activity result content://com.example.myapp.fileprovider/my_images/JPEG_20180318_174300_2454911568678617064.jpg` seems the same to me :/

Comment: Actually the Skia doesnt appear anymore now: I had used the worng imageView to test it. (been staring at the code for too long) When I use the correct imageView, I get this: 03-18 18:14:53.424 14793-14793/com.example.myapp D/SpotMap: Glidejava.lang.RuntimeException: setDataSource failed: status = 0xFFFFFFEA

Comment: Yeah, same here.. but cant take a break, cause I really wana solve this. Yes I tried this too, but it just returned me an empty imageview. I just went over to using glide cause I was hoping for a helpful error message :D

Comment: Manifest: `<provider
            android:name="android.support.v4.content.FileProvider"
           android:authorities="com.example.myapp.fileprovider"
            android:exported="false"
            android:grantUriPermissions="true">
            <meta-data
                android:name="android.support.FILE_PROVIDER_PATHS"
                android:resource="@xml/file_paths">
            </meta-data>
        </provider>`

Comment: Fragment (to get URI):  `photoURI = FileProvider.getUriForFile(this.getActivity(), getActivity().getApplicationContext().getPackageName() + ".fileprovider", photoFile);`     XML: `<external-path name="my_images" path="Android/data/com.example.myapp/files/Pictures"/>`

Comment: Will try what you suggested with the absolute path :)

Comment: Hmmm so weirdly, this is what I get. text file length 0, but existing file + path: 03-18 19:29:16.740 9260-9260/com.example.myapp D/SpotMap: test file length: 0
03-18 19:29:16.741 9260-9260/com.example.myapp D/SpotMap: test file Path: /storage/emulated/0/Android/data/com.example.myapp/files/Pictures/JPEG_20180318_192908_6744038580465499929.jpg

Comment: `getImageBitmapFromAssets` form the post you referred to, returns null as well.. Yes they all get saved (Got a bunch of random photos on my phone now) and I can upload them later on using the `retrieveFromGallery` function...Maybe there will be no Camera function in my app :D

Comment: `<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"
        android:maxSdkVersion="18"/>` Regarding the path and `getExternalFilesDir`, I followed the Android Dvlpmt Tutorial. I am not explicitly asking the user for permission, but according to the tutorial, that is not necessary. I just dont get that I can print out `URI` and `filepath` anytime, but cant load either into my `imageView` object...

Comment: [link](https://developer.android.com/training/camera/photobasics.html#TaskPath) That's the one I followed. Ill give that a try. Otherwise, that'd be great. Really appreciate the help!!

Comment: :D So should I rather not have any path in my manifest? I do refer to the xml there as well. If you want to I can share my github link with you. Do I send you a private msg or how does this work here?

Comment: Yes, but that is what I removed based on the post [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9890757/android-camera-data-intent-returns-null), because passing Extras caused a crash..

Comment: it works for you? this is great news, thank you! But did you pass the `EXTRA_OUTPUT` before `OnActivityResult` or not? I am a bit confused now.

Comment: Yep, you attach it to the camera `Intent`, so the camera app knows where to store the resulting image. Just put the `takePictureIntent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, photoURI);` line back where you had it in the original posted code, right before the `startActivityForResult()` line in `takePicture()`: https://github.com/Vreeni/StreetMovementApp_v2/blob/master/app/src/main/java/com/example/vreeni/StreetMovementApp/MapView_Fragment.java#L880.

Comment: FINALLLYYY. Thank you soo, soo much, I really hadnt expected to get so much help on here. Now I can finally get food and sleep. All the best from Denmark :)

Comment: Phew! Good. Honestly, this isn't really how Stack Overflow is supposed to work, but I felt bad for having caused the confusion in the first place. Sorry about that. Anyhoo, glad you got it working. Cheers!